# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() error

Tags: java, android

### Sorry, this is the second time posting this issue, my code was working fine a few years ago, when I tried to run it now, I got this issue

```
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): Process: com.parents.track, PID: 20161
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONObject.getInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.parents.track.LoginActivity$LogIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:89)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at com.parents.track.LoginActivity$LogIn.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-07 06:04:44.801: E/AndroidRuntime(20161):    ... 4 more
```

---

```
class LogIn extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String >{

    private JsonParser jsonParser;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        String url = "http://localhost/track/login.php?phone=";
        StringBuilder urlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);
        urlStringBuilder.append(arg0[0]);
        SessionManager sessionManager=new SessionManager(context);

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJsonObject(urlStringBuilder, "GET");
        int isLongedIn=0;
        try {
            isLongedIn=json.getInt("LogedIn");
            if(isLongedIn==1){
            String sesion=json.getString("Message");
            sessionManager.createLoginSession(sesion);
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,WelcomeActivity.class);
            Bundle extra = new Bundle();
            extra.putString("HP",phone.getText().toString());
             intent.putExtras(extra);
            startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.w("Json Error", e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Check why `json` is null.

Comment: `isLongedIn=json.getInt("LogedIn");` this line produces NPE, check if `"LogedIn" is correct

Comment: in my browser, when I run localhost/track/login.php?phone=123, I got the response like {"LogedIn":1,"Message":"13"}

Answer (score 0):

Check your server response,it can't find "LogedIn"
in this line: **isLongedIn=json.getInt("LogedIn");**
Add a default  **isLongedIn=json.getInt("LogedIn",0);**
and Check response for have a record by name "LogedIn"

Comment: in my browser, when I run http://localhost/track/login.php?phone=123, I got the response like {"LogedIn":1,"Message":"13"}